# Is there a way to safely kill all apache processes running in background?

Tags: linux, apache, server, process

In a server that I'm working on, There are many apache processes running in background. Is it safe to kill all the processes? If so, please guide me the steps involved in it. I have seen 12 httpd commands running as per result of `top` command, hope it helps in debugging the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can kill httpd process using this command

```
sudo kill `pgrep httpd`
```

Source: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/kill-process-in-linux-or-terminate-a-process-in-unix-or-linux-systems/

OR

Stop the Apache service with:

```
sudo systemctl stop httpd.service
```

Prevent Apache from loading when the system boots:

```
sudo systemctl disable httpd.service
```

Source: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-restart-apache-centos-linux